# Setting window.location.hash vs. $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular with ui-router. I am attempting to refactor some code that looks like this:

```
window.location.hash = "order/" + vm.selectedRow.ID;
```

to this:

```
$state.go("^.order", {orderId: vm.selectedRow.ID} )
```

Changing to use $state.go handles navigating to the route just fine, however, it gets there before the URL has been updated. In the constructor for the associated controller I am grabbing an orderId from the end of the current url and using it in a query. I'm using this code:

```
var strings = window.location.href.split('/');
return strings[strings.length - 1];
```

to get the key.

Should I:
1. Continue to set window.location.hash instead of using $state.go,
2. Refactor to use $location because it lets me get to the pending URL,
3. Pass the ID value to the controller that's used by the new route?

Comment: 4. use the $stateParams service to get the orderId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ui-router` there is no need to use `window.location` in parallel. The `ui-router` offers a service called `$stateParams` which you can inject into your controller. The service provides an object that will have one key per url parameter. In your case the `$stateParams` object will for instance look like this:

```
{ orderId: 2 }
```

However, remember that in controllers the `$stateParams` object will only contain params that were registered with that state. So you will not see params registered on other states.

Another way is to use `$state.params`. You would simply inject `$state` into your controller. The advantage here is, that you can also access query params. Here is a small example:

```
$stateProvider.state('product', {
  url: 'product/:id/:anotherParam/?queryParam',
  controller: 'MyProductController',
});

$state.params; // Contains id, anotherParam, and also queryParam
$stateParams;  // Only contains id and anotherParam
```

Comment: Thanks, since I was already injecting state, I just went with $state.params.orderId